# Impact of the discovery of extra terrestrial life on religion

Tags: society, aliens, religion

If we discover definite proof for extra terrestrial life (more advanced alien civilization) in the near future (imagine the movie contact starring Mathew McConaughey and Jodie Foster), how would it impact us, our society, beliefs and especially religion? What will be the consequences in terms of religious beliefs? Is there any mention of aliens in any religious scriptures? Would it produce more atheists?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding. I suggest you give a look around on the type of questions we answer here and then refine yours. As it is now is both primarily opinion based and too broad, and as such it can be closed.

Comment: Someone will leak the news in the medias .

Comment: NASA need public support for asking a decent budget. So, between telling the truth, and so making a real hype, giving them a good budget, and keeping the discovery secret, creating the frustration of "we know that extraterrestrial life exists but we don't have enough money to study it", I think the choice would be easy

Comment: Most people already think that alien life has been found. The effect would be zero and none. The false alarm has been sounded by Hollywood decades ago and the response was nothing at all. N-o.   o-n-e.   c-a-r-e-s! There's alien life in the forests and in the ocean. There's alien life inside of my body that no one has any understanding of. Alien life on a Trappist exoplanet, who cares? Why care? I have my bills to pay every month and even if they wanted, their wire cash transfer wouldn't arrive in time. They would be irrelevant.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! This question is asking for a brainstorming question and is therefore opinion-based as there is no way to somewhat objectively rate answers against each other. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: They already have found them.

Comment: I think this is far too broad, and opinion based. I think it would also help if you clarified what is meant by 'extra terrestrial life'. There is a big difference between what we would consider as 'intelligent life' and alien microbes found in soil specimens, especially if you are interested in social and religious impact.

Comment: I'm sorry the scope of the answer was broad and subjective. I have rephrased the question. I'm more interested in how it would impact religion and religious fundamentalists.

Comment: There is a movie called Contact which deals (to an extent) with this concept. Extra-terrestrial life is discovered and the opinion of whether this is good or bad varies among the religious. Some see it as the return of God to the world, while others see the attempt which is then made to contact this extra-terrestrial life as wrong.

Comment: @Calllack I was thinking of the Simon Pegg comedy "Paul". One character, upon seeing Paul, initially believes he's Satan but eventually comes to the conclusion that her religion is wrong and she can do whatever she wants. Another character believes him to have been sent by God.

Comment: "Now it came to pass, when men began to multiply on the face of the earth, and daughters were born to them, that the sons of God saw the daughters of men, that they were beautiful; and they took wives for themselves of all whom they chose." (Genesis 6:1-2) "There were giants on the earth in those days, and also afterward, when the sons of God came in to the daughters of men and they bore children to them. Those were the mighty men who were of old, men of renown." (Genesis 6:4)

Comment: Arguably none: consider how little impact Darwin had and has on religious believers.  Some believers would follow the Catholic Church path, and say "Well, God made the aliens too", while the more fundamentalist types would claim that the aliens are really just special effects by godless secular humanists.

Comment: Related: [Paranormal proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/107299/paranormal)

Answer (score 2):

It largely depends on the aliens. If the first we hear of the aliens is a thermonuclear warhead vaporising major cities all over the world, then yes, there will be major panic. If they "come in peace" then there might be.

However, unless the aliens have been studing Earth for a long time, they won't have a clue about earth's governments or public space institutions. And how do they approach NASA without the ESA hearing about it, or even some of the private rocket companies are probably likely to notice *something*.

Your primary question is on how people would react, and the best way to analyse this is to assume that you are "normal." Figure out how you would react, and then spread peoples viewpoints along a spectrum. Or maybe pick a few friends who have different viewpoints to you (eg go find your nearest Christian), and ask what they would do/think.
Just bear in mind that it does depend quite a lot on the specifics.
For example: what if the aliens also had a religion. What if it matched one of ours? What if it didn't match any of them?

---

And what if we discovered them on some far off planet? Well, there would be news headlines for a month or two. "Scientists find aliens on Tau Ceti," "Aliens on Tau Ceti don't live in houses".

From there there are two possibilities:

1. We try get in physical contact with them. This only works if they are more advanced than us, or it's far future. In this case, society will change quite a bit.
2. We try get in radio/communications with them using something faster than light. Society will change slightly. Probably make some large bounds both in science and philosophy. Neurologists and biologists will have a field day.
3. We can't reach them other than in multi-year-long messages. If it takes 4 light years for a signal to reach them, 8 years for a return journey, then how long will it take before we can say "hi" rather than sending prime numbers? Years. As a result, life for most of the planet continues as normal.

How will religions change? In all three cases I suspect there will be a huge dip, but then they will come back. Most religions hinge upon belief in something not proven. (eg life after death). As a result, I imagine they'll survive the message of 'oh, there are are aliens now.' I would even predict evangelists from various religions trying to convert the aliens. Nothing wrong with that.

Do modern religions have aliens in them? How would they change? There would some huge questions raised, and theologians would have a tough time, but would probably end up finding evidence for the existence of the aliens in their religious texts. For example, in Genesis 6:4 (NIV version) you see:

> The Nephilim were on the earth in those days—and also afterward—when
>   the sons of God went to the daughters of humans and had children by
>   them. They were the heroes of old, men of renown.

And there are plenty of references to angels. I'm sure you can see how with a little poking from science, many would conclude that aliens were involved in some way. Actually, some claim it already (just go dig deep into the Ancient Astronaut theories and you'll probably find references to the Bible). However, in Christianity, the biggest "roadblock" is ([source](https://answersingenesis.org/astronomy/alien-life/belief-alien-life-harmless/)):

> In the beginning, God created the earth first, and He made the
>   heavenly bodies throughout the rest of the universe to serve the
>   inhabitants of earth (Genesis 1:14–19). Isaiah 45:18 makes a
>   distinction between God’s role for the earth and the heavens (the rest
>   of the universe).

You also have somewhat humorous situation of (someone else' answer on another site [source](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-proof-of-aliens-in-the-Bible-Why-or-why-not)):

> The God of the bible is definitively alien. It is not human, and not of this earth

Other religions? Well, I'm not as well versed in any others, so you'll have to do your own digging.

Comment: This only works if we discover them coming here. It is far more likely we discover them on an exoplanet somewhere.

Comment: Updated with information on effect on religion in a non-human contact situation.